# What happened to the divine weapons after Mahabharatha war?

Tags: mahabharata, weapon, pashupatastra

What happened to all those divine weapons after completion of Mahabharatha war? Where are those weapons now in kali Yuga? Who possess those weapons now? Were they dismantled or hidden somewhere?

As some people say, weapons are invoked using Mantras, what happened to those mantras after Dwapara Yuga? Does anyone know those mantras now?

Comment: You may be interested in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3236/36

Comment: @AnilKumar - I agree , i retract my vote i wanted to write the comment that it is similar. just so that it gets linked to this question.

Comment: The divine weapons are astras which are not physical. Please see [this post](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/what-is-the-difference-between-astra-shastra/8066#8066).  Since they are not physical they did not exist until it is invoked. Once invoked it would dissipate after revoking or fulfilling its objective.

Comment: It is said that Pashupatastra is sealed by Lord Shiva to prevent the misuse in Kali Yuga. So there was no use of divine weapons after Mahabharatha War. It is said that after the death of Krishna, Kali Yuga began and no one had the knowledge of divine weapons.

Comment: They are on moon

Answer (score 4):

Actually let me explain the term divine weapon :
Divine weapon is actually an ordinary weapon which would get 'divine' powers after chanting special mantras.

eg If we take an ordinary arrow and chant Varunas mantra it would become Varunastra and so on .

It is stated that Vrishaketu, Karnas son was the last person in the Earth to have the knowledge of such mantras for divine weapons . He was taught this by Arjun (after Kurukshetra war) . He promised Krishna that he would not disclose the mantra to any others. So with his death the knowledge of such mantras also perished . Hence we cannot find it any more.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.  It's not enough to say "It is stated that", you should specify exactly where in the Mahabharata or other scripture it is stated.

Comment: Its not true, Mantras are just thoughts, most powerful word is Aum itself which can produce highest reverberation in universe, So those weapons were same as indian army, e.g. bharamstra is atom bomb.

Answer (score 1):

These are given in various books.They vary depending upon the sources .There were 3-4 types of Pashupatastra.
A book in Marathi--Mantra Shastra by Shankaracharya Khare has given a few.Nothing happens after chanting them.This was sound power and since we do not know how to convert the same into other forms of energy,these mantras are useless.

Comment: Cite the sources for your  claims. There were 3-4 types of Pashupatastras? Could you quote where you read this?