# Most recent use of Astras?

Tags: weapon

I want to know the most recent use of Astras either by Gods themselves or by learned individuals.

Are there any references to use of astras after mahabharatha by learned individuals?

Comment: You can see this question  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8957/3500