# Why no Divine Weapons in Kali Yuga?

Tags: kali-yuga, weapon

The ancient scriptures speak a lot on divine weapons used in the earlier yugas. There are mention of Brahmastra, Rudrastra, Narayanastra etc. But, why these weapons do not exist in the kali Yuga?

Comment: see this http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8957/3500

Comment: My friend you see the lost of astras is never - ending. Many powerful warriors have unlimited astras (Arjuna, Parashurama, Rama etc.). Anyone in this Yuga, the Kali Yuga can obtain astras. All the personnneeds to do is a long meditation and not only astras, but you can also ask for wishes from gods as well. Also, there is no need for any astras . Technology has improved. But surely old is gold!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All divya astras are weapons of a single divine energy " **Tejas**" or ﬁery energy.” .
This energy is channelled into the physical world by their wielders, with the **correct mantras**.
Through incantations (mantras)a divya astra is generally united with a normal weapon (sastra) typically arrows – which
obviously makes the Divine astra very very effective. Divine weapons are closely connected with  emotions such as rage and anger. When unleashed they
invoke all the raw power of a warrior’s fury,  infused with the tejas of the gods, and thus are capable of laying waste hundreds of opponents
in one concentrated act of violence

Most divine weapons are named after the deities who preside over them, and, in general, they manifest the natural phenomena associated
with the particular powers they reﬂect. For example, the "Agneya astra" (“Fire-weapon”) belonging to Agni, the god of ﬁre and
the Vaarun astra (“Water-weapon”) belonging to Varun . a, the water deity, creates water. Thus, a large array of divine weapons exists,
which produce storms, lightning, ﬁre, wind, typhoons, mountains, rain etc.

> one needs "Tapas" and self "Tejas "both to acquire and employ divine
>   weapons successfully.
>
> But due to change in time (Kaliyuga) Power(bala), intuition (buddhi)
>   ,Tejasa ,tolerance, Foresight (pratipatti) has declined and  this
>   consequently resulted  loss in the potential life expectancy of
>   humans.  So in kaliyuga no one can employ divine weapons,  This is
>   because of a decline in e potential amount of tejas any given
>   individual can acquire. Thus the divine weapons are withdrawn from
>   circulation ,and returned to their Divine owners.**

Ref.-DIVINE WEAPONS AND TEJAS IN THE TWO INDIAN EPICS (PDF paper)
     by JARROD L. WHITAKER ,University of Texas at Austin.

Comment: Hey, I liked your answer very much. According to the scriptures, there would be certain people who still know the art and have the knowledge (Paramgyata). who are they and how can I find them??