# Are Itihasas and Puranas the only classes of scripture in which celestial weapons are used?

Tags: vedas, puranas, weapon, itihasa

Ramayana, Mahabharata and many Puranas relate conflicts in which Divyastras like Brahmastra get used.

Do these weapons occur in earlier scriptures like Vedas and Brahmanas or any scriptures written after the Puranas?

Comment: The following questions are already existing on this topic. Please check (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8957/3869)and (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9537/why-no-divine-weapons-in-kali-yuga?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about weapon like brahmastra but some other divine weapons are present in vedas.

- Rigveda1:155:2

  > 2. Your Soma-drinker keeps afar your furious rush, Indra and Visnu, when ye come with all your might. That which hath been directed well at mortal man, **bow-armed Krsanu's arrow**, ye turn far aside.

Here, Vedas tell about *Krsanu's arrow*. I think that it is a name of some weapon.

Comment: What is majcal?

Comment: @Wikash_ it is majical.

Comment: What is the meaning of it?

Comment: @Wikash_ I used this word for the power of divyastras.

Comment: Do you mean magical?