# Where can I find the details about the weapons that kshatriyas had at olden times?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, weapon, kshatriya

Are there any Vedas, Puranas, or holy scripts that contain their descriptions?

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Since you’re a new user and you may not be aware: If you’re satisfied with the below answer, you can accept it by pressing the tick (✔️) sign below the voting arrows. If you like the answer you can upvote by pressing the upward arrow on the answer. Thanks:) hope you like it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Agni Purana](https://archive.org/details/puran_agni/page/n483/mode/2up) contains a description of most of the weapons found in olden times. Chapter 249 divides weapons into the following categories:

1. Yantramukta (projectile weapons such as the sling (kshepani) or the bow),
2. Pāṇimukta (hurling weapons such as the javelin (tomara),
3. Muktasandhārita  (weapons that can be used for either hurling or thrusting, such as the spear),
4. Amukta (weapons that do not leave the hand, such as the sword).

A list of weapons and their techniques is provided in Chapter 252 of the Agni Purana:

1. Khaḍga (sword) and shield (1-4)
2. Pāśa (noose) (5-6)
3. Vyastapāśa (7)
4. Chakra (discus) (8)
5. Śūla (spear) (9)
6. Tomara (10)
7. Paraśu (axe) (13)
8. Mudgara (14)
9. Bhindipāla (15)
10. Laguḍa (15)
11. Vajra (16)
12. Paṭṭiśa (16)
13. Kṛpāṇa (dagger) (17)
14. Kṣepaṇī (sling) (18)
15. Gadā (mace) (19-23.5)
16. Bow and arrow (this finds mention separately in Chapter 251)

Comment: But do these scriptures contain the process or methodology that shall be followed in order to obtain them??

Comment: @pushkarsingh Obtain them as in? You make them in a smelting factory and use them. Today Sikhs still use chakra, sword shield. Wrestling akhaada use gada. Bow and arrow is very rare but existent. Spear is found generally everywhere miscellaneous. Even south India kalaripayattu know how to make most of these.

Comment: I know that, but in earlier times the bows had different powers and could even bring the rains in a drought region, so how can I or where can I find detailed descriptions about the superior weapons.                For example:.        Sarpastra, pashuptastra,

Comment: Well you have the dhanurveda having a feeble mention, But the art of obtaining such weapons is lost in Kaliyuga. See [why no divine weapons in Kaliyuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9537/why-no-divine-weapons-in-kali-yuga/13611?r=SearchResults#13611). These were obtained earlier from god or guru. Also though the dhanurveda has the mantra, but the exact art has been lost so even if you chant the mantra, it won’t be effective, you have to first be granted mantra diksha etc and be given the weapon by the god/guru, which in Kaliyuga is not possible as of today. @pushkarsingh

Comment: @pushkarsingh so if you’re temporarily satisfied with this answer you can accept it by clicking the tick button. Thank you :)